# Delimiter a row after a specified number of characters in the line of text with bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, csv

I have a DataFile.txt with multiple lines like this

```
010255500060010123066000952367006U00000000001721SMITH JOHN
536818991298231894872315612145497F00000000001721STUART FEDERIC
```

Every character in one row represent a number (position), and needed to add a delimiter (space) based on the character position in every line. Example:

- Case 1: Character #2
- Case 2: Character #10
- Case 3: Character #26
- Case 4: Character #44
- Case 5: Character #48

...and so on

Then the output for this rules and the NewFile.txt:

```
01 02555000 6001012306600095 2367006U0000000000 1721 SMITH JOHN
53 68189912 9823189487231561 2145497F0000000000 1721 STUART FEDERIC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use in `gnu-awk` [FIELDWIDTHS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS = "2 8 16 18 4 100"; OFS=" "}
     {$1=$1; print}' DataFile.txt
```

you get,

```
01 02555000 6001012306600095 2367006U0000000000 1721 SMITH JOHN
53 68189912 9823189487231561 2145497F0000000000 1721 STUART FEDERIC
```

Comment: can be golfed to `gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="2 8 16 18 4 99" '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: Thanks You!
@glennjackman is other way and both of them are very useful ways to do that changes in the file.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say:

```
sed -E 's/(.{2})(.{8})(.{16})(.{18})(.{4})/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 /' filename
```

For very old GNU seds, you may have to use `-r` instead of `-E` (this is for extended regex syntax. Without that, you'd need a lot of backslashes that don't exactly aid readability).

This simply captures groups of letters -- `.{n}` matches n arbitrary letters -- and reassembles them with added spaces.

**Addendum:**

If it is important that the numbers used are the same as in the question, consider Perl:

```
perl -pe 'for $i (48, 44, 26, 10, 2) { substr($_, $i, 0) = " "; }' filename
```

...since replacing zero-length substrings is the same as inserting. The numbers have to descend for this to work so that already-inserted spaces don't mess up the count.

Note that this is likely to offer worse performance than the sed approach (because more intermediate strings have to be calculated), which may or may not be a problem depending on file size. However, if performance is not a consideration and you prefer working with absolute positions over field widths, this works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I will prefer the awk way